# Can I apply the floor function to the left- and right hand side this way?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm wondering if I can apply the floor function to both sides like below? This isn't all I want to do I just want to know if the operation is legal. Thanks!
$$ a + x  < b + y  \to \lfloor a + x \rfloor < \lfloor b + y \rfloor $$

EDIT:
To clarify I'd only like to know if the operation is allowed. What I'd actually like to is prove $$a \leq b \to \lfloor a \rfloor \leq \lfloor b\rfloor$$ but I want to know if I can come up with this proof by applying the floor function operation to both sides kind of like adding 1 to both sides makes the inequality still hold.

Comment: NO! For example 1.5 < 1.8 but [1.5]=1=[1.8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is a **function**, by definition, if $a=b$ then $f(a)=f(b)$.  The floor function is an example of a function and so you have $a=b$ implies $\lfloor a\rfloor = \lfloor b\rfloor$.

Now... some functions will retain inequalities too.  If a function is *monotonic increasing* that means by definition that if $a\leq b$ then $f(a)\leq f(b)$.  The floor function is an example of a monotonic increasing function.  That is to say, if $a\leq b$ then it is true that $\lfloor a\rfloor \leq \lfloor b\rfloor$.

Not every function is monotonic increasing however.  Take for example $f(x)=x^2$.  You have $-3\leq 1$ but $(-3)^2\not\leq (1)^2$.

Finally, some functions will retain *strict* inequalities as well.  If a function is *strictly monotonic increasing* that means by definition that if $a<b$ then $f(a)<f(b)$.  The floor function is *not* strictly monotonic, for example how $1.2<1.5$ but $\lfloor 1.2\rfloor \not\lt \lfloor 1.5\rfloor$ since they both result in the same value of $1$.

---

As for a hint on how to prove that $a\leq b\implies \lfloor a\rfloor \leq \lfloor b\rfloor$, rewrite $b$ as $a+(b-a)$ and recognize that $(b-a)\geq 0$.  Further, apply the definition of the floor function as being the largest integer less than or equal to its input.

> Let $x\geq 0$.  Then let $c = \lfloor a\rfloor$ be the largest integer less than or equal to $a$.  It follows that $c$ is *an* integer which is less than or equal to $a+x$, whether it is the largest one or not... and so whatever the largest integer less than or equal to $a+x$ is will be at least as large as $c$.  As such we have $\lfloor a\rfloor \leq \lfloor a+x\rfloor$, showing that the floor function is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

We can write,  using  the fractional part, that
$$
\eqalign{
  & a \le b\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  \left\lfloor a \right\rfloor  + \left\{ a \right\} \le \left\lfloor b \right\rfloor  + \left\{ b \right\} \hfill \cr 
  0 \le \left\{ a \right\},\left\{ b \right\} < 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\{ a \right\} - \left\{ b \right\} \le \left\lfloor b \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor a \right\rfloor  \cr} 
$$

At the same time,  you can write your inequality as
$$
\eqalign{
  & a \le b\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le b - a\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le \left\lfloor {b - a} \right\rfloor  + \left\{ {b - a} \right\}\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le \left\lfloor {\left\lfloor b \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor a \right\rfloor  + \left\{ b \right\} - \left\{ a \right\}} \right\rfloor  + \left\{ {b - a} \right\}\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le \left\lfloor b \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor a \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\left\{ b \right\} - \left\{ a \right\}} \right\rfloor  + \left\{ {b - a} \right\}\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 0 \le \left\lfloor b \right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor a \right\rfloor  - \left[ {\left\{ b \right\} < \left\{ a \right\}} \right] + \left\{ {b - a} \right\} \cr} 
$$
where the square brackets denote the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)

And, apart from obvious manipulations, I do not know other ways to put it for, general $a, \, b$.